# John 14:26b ...IN MY NAME

Tags: john, jesus

I only came here to find something out about the phrase; "...will send in My name" specifically the 'in my name' part of John 14:26.

What is the point AND the meaning of this phrase, "in my name"? Would its exclusion change anything about the statement Jesus is making? Since it's Jesus making it, I have to assume He intended for it (1) to be said, and (2) said exactly as it is and in NO OTHER way.

Any takers who can explain in very simple, basic, moronic words that a 4 year old can understand? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's interesting that everything Jesus has been talking about in the preceding chapters of John has to do with Jesus speaking the Father's  words and doing the works of the Father.

> The words that I speak to you, I do not speak from Myself; but the Father dwelling in Me does His works.  John 14:10

> The word that you hear is not Mine, but that of the Father having sent Me.  John  14:24

He is talking to his disciples right before He would be going  to the Father.

> I am going to the Father.
> John 14:12

He begins  tell his disciples that they can request things in His name,  then He will be doing things on their requests.

> If you ask me anything in my name, I will do it.  John 14:15

Jesus said He would be asking the Father to give his disciples another counselor, The spirit of truth that would be with them for the eon.

> I will ask the Father, and another Comforter He will give to you, that he may remain with you -- to the age;  John 14:16

He then tells them that the Father will send the counselor, the Holy Spirit to them in  Jesus's name.

> These things have I spoken to you remaining with you.  Now the counselor, the Holy Spirit which the Father will be sending in My name, that will be teaching you all, and reminding you of all that I said to you.  John. 14:26

> When the Counselor has come, whom I will send to you from the Father, the Spirit of truth, who proceeds from the Father, he will testify about me.  John 15:26

After Jesus completed his work the Father had sent him to do, the cross was now completed and the door was open for them to receive the spirit because of His name, the name of Jesus.

The work of Jesus begins in his disciples , just as the Father worked in Jesus.

Jesus's name is being glorified  by the Father and the proof is the Holy Spirit being given after He has been glorified.

Now this he said about the Spirit, whom those who believed in him were to receive, for as yet the Spirit had not been given, because Jesus was not yet glorified.  John 7:39

> The holy ghost could not be given until after Christ was glorified. Acts 2 tells us that Christ is now “by the right hand of God exalted… [and] that God hath made that same Jesus, whom ye have crucified, both Lord and Christ.”
> Since the holy spirit had just been given to the 120 disciples assembled together, we know that Christ’s glorification had already taken place. There can be nothing more glorious than being “by the right hand of God exalted, and being made both Lord and Christ”. This was all accomplished through the death and resurrection of Christ. There would have been no glorification without those two events."

[Iswasandwillbe.com](https://www.iswasandwillbe.com/what-is-the-glorification-of-christ/)

Jesus, or in Hebrew, Yeshua.  This name is a compound name in the pattern of the Old Testament, meaning: "JEHOVAH is SAVIOR."

OP asked;

"What is the point AND the meaning of this phrase, "in my name"? "

I would say that the point in all of this is the beginning of Jesus's name being revealed first to His  disciples and later on All will know what Jesus  the savior means.

> that in the Name of JESUS every knee should bow, of beings in Heaven, of those on the earth, and of those in the underworld,  Philippians 2:10

Comment: I have edited only to highlight the quotation as a reference. Please feel free to rollback, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Nigel,  I have often wondered when quoting someone else if that should be indented as well.  Now I know, thanks to your edit.

Answer (score 2):

To be sent in someone's name means to be authorised to do and to say what the sender requires of the one sent. The one sent is like an ambassador, and the Son of God was sent from heaven, by God the Father, to represent the Father while on earth, as the man Jesus. There was a particular work to be done, and Jesus totally accomplished that work to his dying breath, "It is finished!"

The religious authorities of his day set great store by having the authority of an esteemed one, to speak as a follower and a representative of that one's teaching. The Rabbis claimed to have the authority of previous Rabbis who were greatly revered. That is why there was astonishment when Jesus began to teach in the synagogues, "For they were astonished at his doctrine, for he taught them as one that had authority, and not as the scribes" (Mark 1:22).

They would quote from previous religious teachers and say nothing of themselves, basing their authority on the authority of the name of the person they were disciples of. An unbroken line of such authority, from generation to generation, was vital to them. That is why they challenged Jesus, demanding to know on whose authority he spoke and performed miracles, as here when Jesus said:

> "I am the light of the world: he that followeth me shall not walk in
> darkness, but shall have the light of life." The Pharisees therefore
> said unto him, "Thou bearest record of thyself; thy record is not
> true." Jesus answered and said unto them, "Though I bear record of
> myself, yet my record is true: for I know whence I came, and whither I
> go; but ye cannot tell whence I come, and whither I go. Ye judge after
> the flesh, I judge no man. And yet if I judge, my judgment is true;
> for I am not alone, but I and the Father that sent me. It is written
> in your law, that the testimony of two men is true. I am one that bear
> witness of myself, and the Father that sent me beareth witness of me."
> Then said they unto him, "Where is thy Father?" Jesus answered , "Ye
> neither know me, nor my Father: if ye had known me, ye should have
> known my Father also." - John 8:12-19

**This shows what Jesus meant in John 14:26b - 'in my name'.** He had come from heaven in the Father's name and authority, to speak and do the very things of God. ***There could be no higher authority for Jesus.*** Then, after he returned to the Father in glory, his disciples could "preach fearlessly in *the name of Jesus*" (Acts 9:27). Also, as "Philip preached the good news of the kingdom of God and *the name of Jesus Christ,* they were baptised, both men and women" (Acts 8:12). Peter also said, when asked by the high priest, "By what power or what name did you do this?":

> "It is by the name of Jesus Christ of Nazareth, whom you crucified but
> whom God raised from the dead, that this man stands before you healed.
> He [the resurrected Christ] is 'the stone you builders rejected, which
> has become the capstone'. Salvation is found in no-one else, for
> **there is no other name under heaven given to men by which we must be saved**." Acts 4:9-12 - ***the name of Jesus Christ!***

These biblical texts, including John 14:26, mean that **"in the name of" means "in the authority and power of" - that one.**

Answer (score 1):

The pertinent noun here is ὄνομα (onoma) = "name" about which BDAG offers these helpful comments:

> The belief in the efficacy of the name is extremely old; its origin
> goes back to the most ancient times and most primitive forms of
> intellectual and religious life. It has exhibited an extraordinary
> vitality. The period of our literature also sees - within and without
> the new community of believers - in the name something real, a piece
> of very nature of the personality whom it designates, expressing the
> person's qualities and powers.  Accordingly, names, especially, holy
> names, are revered and used in customary practices and ritual ... In
> Israelite tradition the greatest reverence was paid to the holy name
> of God and to its numerous paraphrases or substitutes ... The
> Judeo-Christians revere the use and name of God and, of course,
> Jesus ...

Thus, When Jesus promises, in John 14:26, that the Father would send the Advocate/Comforter (= Holy Spirit) in "my Name", He is continuing the great promise begun in John 14:12 about the coming Holy Spirit, namely:

- V13 - we can act in the "name" of Jesus, ie, in Jesus' authority and in keeping with Jesus' will
- V14 - Jesus will do anything asked for in Jesus name, ie, in Jesus' authority and in keeping with Jesus' will.  This includes:
- V15 - keeping Jesus' commandments
- V17 - the Spirit of Truth (the Holy Spirit lives in us and leads us into all truth, John 16:13)
- V18 - Jesus would not, despite leaving this world, leave the disciples as orphans but would send the advocate/Comforter (= Holy Spirit) in Jesus name, ie, in Jesus' authority and in keeping with Jesus' will
- V21 - Jesus reveals Himself to the one has the Holy Spirit
- V23 - keeps Jesus' word
- V26 - the Advocate/Comforter "will teach you all things and will remind you of everything I have told you."

That is, to act in Jesus' name is to act on Jesus' behalf with the authority and will of Jesus.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, the *Milk*:

The Spirit of God is the Father's consciousness that He shares perfectly with His begotten Son, who then shares his spirit (consciousness) with us.  In this way, the Spirit of God can only be accessed through the Son or in his name.

The longer more complete answer, the *Solid Food*:

There is only 1 eternal Spirit and this would be the Holy Spirit of God.  And by God, I'm referring to "thee only true God" of Jesus Christ.

John 17:3

> And this is life eternal, that they might know thee the only true God, and Jesus Christ, whom thou hast sent

Jesus tells the woman at the well that his God and Father is a Spirit.

John 4:23-24

> 23 But the hour cometh, and now is, when the true worshippers shall worship the Father in spirit and in truth: for the Father seeketh such to worship him. 24 God is a Spirit: and they that worship him must worship him in spirit and in truth.

Paul makes it clear that there is 1 Spirit.

Eph4:4

> There is one body, and one Spirit, even as ye are called in one hope of your calling; 5 One Lord, one faith, one baptism, 6 One God and Father of all, who is above all, and through all, and in you all.

Therefore,I will be continuing this explanation with the premise that the Holy Spirit of God **IS** our Father's Spirit and not a completely other eternal spirit and/or person.

To use the parlance of the times....The Holy Spirit of God is the Father's **consciousness**.

Humans, born in the image of the Creator, also have a consciousness. **This is our individualized seed(spirit) of the Spirit from the original and now corrupted seed of Adam.**  Its who each of us identifies as; what you are besides your flesh suit.  Seeds produce more seeds.

Modern man-made concepts concerning consciousness are still undeveloped and not fully defined. To put it simply your consciousness is your instantaneous thoughts and emotions.

The Father shares His Spirit (consciousness) fully and perfectly with the Son.  That is how we say the Son is "IN" the Father and vice-a-versa.  They are ONE.

Our Master, the Son, likewise shares his holy spirit (his consciousness) with us.  That is how we are ONE with the Father.  We are in our Master who is perfectly IN his God.

Acts 2:33

> Therefore being by the right hand of God exalted, and having received of the Father the **promise of the holy spirit**, he hath shed forth this, which ye now see and hear.

The holy spirit mentioned here is part of the glory promise Jesus received when he was exalted as we read above; a counterpart to his new spirit body.
That is how we know this holy spirit is something different than the Spirit of God which is the Father's Spirit.  He was immersed with the Father's Spirit during his baptism. Still 1 Spirit however, because they share consciousness.

In the end, all of the children of Elohim, will inherit a holy spirit, which will be one with the Spirit of the Father.  At that time, God will be all in all.  There is only 1 eternal consciousness and this is the Spirit of YHWH, the Eternal One.

***Who is the Parakletos***

John 14:26

> But the **Parakletos**, G3875 this holy spirit, whom the **Father will send in my name**, he shall teach you all things, and bring all things to your remembrance, whatsoever I have said unto you.

John 15:26

> But when the **Parakletos** G3875 is come, whom **I will send unto you from the Father**, even this spirit of truth, which **proceedeth from the Father**, he shall testify of **me**:

John 16:7

> Nevertheless I tell you the truth; It is expedient for you that **I go away**: for if I go not away, the *Parakletos* G3875 will not come unto you; but if I depart, **I will send him** unto you.

The **parakletos** in chapter 14 is the Risen Son. I can say this with confidence because John, the same author of the verse in question, also wrote this verse:

1John 2:2

> My little children, these things write I unto you, that ye sin not. And if any man sin, we have a **Parakletos** with the Father, ***Jesus Christ*** the righteous:

Its important to note that in the 14th chapter of John, Jesus has not been glorified.  He is speaking as the human Messiah, NOT the Risen Son in all his the glory of his inheritance.  The Risen Son, inherits a spirit body and a spirit consciousness that he can now share just as his God and Father shares His Spirit (consciousness) perfectly with him.

The Risen Son is the Vine and we are the branches.  The Spirit of God proceeds from the Father and moves through the Son to the rest of the children of God.

The Vine is the only pathway to the Father, and therefore, is the only doorway the Father uses to share with us His Spirit; upgrading our corrupted old spirit seed with the new incorruptible seed by way of the Risen Son who is the seed inside all of us who are *born again*.

***In conclusion then, the Father will send His Holy Spirit in the name of the Son. You can't receive it any other way.  Jesus is thee way.***

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is a bakery where the best cake in the shop is not for sale. Now the owner has a son, an only son, whom he loves dearly. Because he loves the son, the  father also loves those who love the son. In the name of the son, the father will give the cake to the son’s friends.

“In his name” is the point where the father and the son’s friends meet and come together. Without “in his name” they remain strangers and there is no connection. The friends love the son and come to the father in the name of the son; in his name, the father loves them and gives to them. It is a connection based on love, but this love that cannot be shown by merely invoking a name or saying it in a certain way.

> The one who has My commandments and keeps them is the one who loves
> Me; and the one who loves Me will be loved by My Father” – Jn 14:21

The way to demonstrate one’s love for the son is by obeying his commands, just as the son shows his love for the father by doing what the father has commanded.

> So that the world may know that I love the Father, I do exactly as the
> Father commanded Me – Jn 14:31